# How to load 1 week data into SQL table from Flat file in SSIS

Tags: sql

I want to load flat file data into SQL table on daily basic.But my table hold on 1 week data. After 7 days previous data will deleted from my table and new data will append.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your flat file delimited? Commas? Tabs? How many fields are there? what types are they?

If you only want one weeks worth of data in the table at any one time, you will need to delete after you do the daily import. If you import daily but only delete once a week you will have almost two weeks worth of data in the table.

What have you tried already?

Comment: I am having only three columns in flat file[id,name,date].I am loading today's data into my sql table.Tomorrow i will load next day data. After one week my table contain 7 days data. While loading 8th days data first i have to delete 1st day data and laod 8th day data......

Answer (score 0):

before/after you run the import, delete any data that is more than 6 days old